# BS 220 GPS NMEA - UBLOX using U-center

Tags: quadcopters, software, gps

I have a quad with an omnibus f4 v3 flight controller an FS-ia6b receiver. I also have a bs 220 gps wired in correctly to the flight controller however it is outputting NMEA and this has many errors. I'm trying to change it from NMEA to UBLOX using the u-center software but can't figure out how to do this can someone please help?